# Is there a way to make sure a sprite collides with 2 sprites in a group?

Tags: python, pygame

So, i'm trying to make it so when my player collides with a tile in the group self.tiles, and if my player is running at the tile in the right direction, set the player back to the left of that tile. Problem is, i can't use

```
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
            if tile.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
```

as, since i also have a vertical collision where it uses the same thing to detect whether a player is standing on it. Only difference between vertical and horizontal, is that the player would collide with two tiles at once in horizontal, so i'd like to see if there's a way to detect if a player touches 2 of the tile sprites in self.tiles.sprites (if there's a more efficient method i'd like to hear it as well)

Comment: The code looks to already be using PyGame Sprites, so why not use `pygame.sprite.groupcollide()` ?  Use a single-sprite group containing the player for one group, the tiles for the second group.  Then check if the returned list length is > 1.  If it is, the player collided with >1 sprite.

Comment: Oh i thought this also returned only a boolean not a list i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide):

> Return a list containing all Sprites in a Group that intersect with another Sprite.

So if you want to know all the tiles the player collides with, you have to use `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`:

```py
listOfCollindingTiles = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, tile, False)
for tile in listOfCollindingTiles:
    print(tile.rect)
```

---

Another way to handle horizontal and vertical movements and collisions is to perform the horizontal and vertical movements separately:

- Move the player in x-direction
- Detect the collisions and limit the movement of the player in X-direction
- Move the player in y-direction
- Detect the collisions and limit the movement of the player in y-direction

You can try to separate only the collision detection and the limitation of the players position depending on the movement axis and not the movement itself, however this may not completely solve your problem. It will be a problem if you always fall down slightly, even if you are standing on a tile, so the horizontal collision detection will always detect a collision with the tiles you are standing on.

Your code should look something like this:

```py
# do the horizontal movement here, something like:
# player.rect.x += player.direction.x

collide_x = False
collisioncheck=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player,self.tiles,False,False)
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
    if player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
        if player.direction.x > 0:
            player.rect.right = tile.rect.left
            collide_x = True
        elif player.direction.x < 0:
            player.rect.left = tile.rect.right
            collide_x = True
if collide_x:
    player.direction.x = 0

# do the vertical movement here, something like:
# player.rect.y += player.direction.y

collide_y = False
collisioncheck=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.player,self.tiles,False,False)
for tile in self.tiles.sprites():
    if player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect):
        if player.direction.y > 0:
            player.rect.bottom = tile.rect.top
            collide_y = True
        elif player.direction.y <= 0:
            player.rect.top = tile.rect.bottom
            collide_y = True
if collide_y:
   player.direction.y = 0
```